# Why does google.com not use double quotes around the values of some HTML attributes?

Tags: html

I was looking at the sourcecode of google.com (the web-rendered version ofc. ;-)) and I noticed that they don't always use double quotes around the values of some HTML attributes, like:

```
<a onclick=gbar.qs(this) class=gbmt id=gb_10 href="http://books.google.com/bkshp?hl=en&tab=wp&authuser=0" onclick="gbar.logger.il(1,{t:10})">Books</a>
```

What's the advantage of coding your site like this?

source: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Comment: You transfer less data over the wire. Not an issue for most sites, but every bit counts when you are google scale.

Comment: Don't do it.  Obviously, it works, but it's a bad habit.  That HTML is not valid XHTML.  IMHO, you should at least try to be XHTML compliant.

Comment: @gilly3 - Why? HTML5 is not XHTML compliant, nor is it XML compliant.

Comment: @gilly3 please don't give blanket answers like this that are of preference/need only. I'm an XML/XHTML advocate too, but to tell someone who is using HTML that not using quotes is a bad habit is completely incorrect.

Comment: @KevinPeno - It's not an answer, it's a comment.  IMHO == "In my humble opinion". If I were interviewing a software developer and he showed code that didn't quote HTML attributes, that would be a strike against him in my book because it's a bad habit. The arguments for it are weaker than the arguments against it. I feel the same way about indenting JavaScript or HTML (or any code for that matter).  It's not a matter of being valid, it's a matter of good habits.

Comment: @gilly3 wording choice aside (me saying answer vs. comment), your post did not imply opinion, hence my comment. I don't think we disagree anywhere else ;)

Comment: @Oded - Because, in my opinion, it's a bad habit, regardless of whether the language allows it. I also don't like single statement control structures without curly braces in JavaScript.  Another bad habit, IMHO, though not as bad as omitting quotes in attributes.

Comment: @gilly3 - My point is that saying that everything should be XHTML is not very constructive. Back it up.

Comment: @gilly3 HTML is not XHTML and requiring HTML to be XHTML compliant doesn't make sense. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Rob - Fair enough.  But *trying* to be XHTML compliant and *requiring* it are not the same thing.  The web is dynamic, requirements change.  You may find yourself in a circumstance where you want to take advantage of a system or service that requires XHTML. Quoting attributes is not hard when you do it from the beginning, but to have to go back through each line of code and add in quotes is a pain that is easily avoidable. It's easier to just develop a good habit than it is to go back and redo your code when you suddenly find you want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because HTML doesn't care. Quotes are not required. In the case of a boolean attribute, it doesn't even need a value either at times (ex. `disabled` vs. `disabled="disabled"`). Only XML (and XHTML served with an XML mimetype) cares about syntax in this way because XML spec defines these are required.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is done to minimize the size of HTML of the page as much as possible. Because when you are serving as many pages as google every byte counts. I remember quite a while ago there was an article about it. They also don't close a lot of the opening tags and some other stuff.

EDIT: Found the article from 2 years ago: http://blog.errorhelp.com/2009/06/27/the-highest-traffic-site-in-the-world-doesnt-close-its-html-tags/

Comment: "The Google homepage and search results pages don’t end their <body> and <html> elements." interesting!

Comment: @Mr.Pallazzo Because neither is required.